# search number in a cell containing numbers comma separated excel

Tags: excel

Im looking for a formula that can check if the numbers in `column C` exist in `Column A` and return value `Column B`

[image: image 1]

Search Gives me the value

[image: image 2]

Comment: Another Homework Question!? `COUNTIFS` is the key here OR `VLOOKUP`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show what has worked/hasn't worked, any errors, etc. you're getting from your attempts.  Have you looked in to `Vlookup()`, with `Mid()` maybe?

Comment: Return the values where?

Comment: I have tried Vlookup(), Search(), Find(), 
I tired =INDEX(B2:B8,IF(SEARCH(C2,A2:A8),ROW(A2:A8),"")) but didnt work

Comment: Please put the formulas that got you the closest in the OP using edit, not in the comments.

Comment: I added one more pic in the question. im getting this incorrect error #values, which is again causing problems

Comment: Please put the formula as text and not a photo.

Comment: =INDEX(B1:B10,IF(SEARCH(C4,A2:A10),ROW(A2:A10),""))

Comment: didnt get any help on this yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick and dirty way I have done it in the past.

Copy column C and insert before the column you want to look up (A in this case). Vlookup will only search to the right, so you need to use this column for your vlookup. Note that the last argument "true" will give you a fuzzy match rather than an exact match. This should allow you to find text within cell text.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,TRUE)
```

See for screenshot:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/137b7c3a382841eeb8ebd34f7ac1e113.png

When done, you can copy and paste values, then delete the inserted column (A). Alternatively, you can create a formula so column A always equals the column C. Then right click the column and hide. That will allow formulas to continue updating as you make changes.

Also, a word of caution. It looks like your numbers are all stored as text. For the purposes of what you are doing now, that appears to be a good thing. Just be aware that some functions may not behave as expected because of this.